# Forward protocol implementation on category to class which includes it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang

I have a category on NSobject which implements two protocols. In that implementation One of them is fully implemented but the method that complies to the protocol calls a method for the other protocol. What I want to do is to forward the method implentation responsibility to any class which would like to import that category. That means to supress the not implemented method warning and make the compiler complain in the importing class. Is this possible?

Comment: When you create a category on `NSObject`, then any class that is a subclass of `NSObject` gets those category methods, whether or not they specifically import the category file or not. So I think you're misunderstanding a little bit how categories work. The compiler will complain that they're missing in the category, not in the subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, when you create a category on `NSObject`, then any subclass of `NSObject` gets those methods whether or not the subclass has an import statement for the category. So a category doesn't get selectively added to subclasses that import it.

What you could do to achieve what you want is to remove from the category the part where it says you implement the protocols, so that all you have is the methods implemented there. Then the compiler won't complain about your category missing some required protocol methods. Then when somebody has a subclass, they can specify that their subclass implements those protocols, and they can implement the missing methods to make the compiler not complain in their subclass.

Comment: Maybe I have the situation mixed up in my head, but I don't think this will work. You won't be able to send the messages without complaint in the category unless you conform to the protocol, will you?

Comment: @Chuck The subclass will conform to the protocol, not the category. And for calling a method within the category for something that may or may not be there, it can use `respondsToSelector:` and `performSelector:` to make the calls.

Comment: But if `self` is not known to conform to the protocol when you compile the category, you'll get complaints when you try to send messages from the protocol to `self`. That's what I was saying.

Comment: @Chuck That's why I said to use `respondsToSelector:` and `performSelector:`, because it won't care one way or the other if it conforms to a protocol, it will check to see if the method it wants to call can be called on that object.

Comment: I ended up with Gavins solution slightly tweaked. I implement the NSCoding protocol in an NSObject category. I havae an "GenericArchiverProtocol" implementation which imports the category and requeires one method "getPropertyNamesForGenericArchiver". But in the Category in which I implement NSCoding i use "conformsToProtocol" and cast self to the protocol and use it just to acquire that propertyNames. In addition if I do not conform, I just go ret but it could be an exception as well. Any class conformin to the GenericArchiverProtocol will have to implement the needed method (warning shown).

Answer (score 2):

You can either make the method @optional or give NSObject a dummy implementation that just gives an error along the lines of "This method must be overridden." There's no way to get a compile-time warning in this situation for some classes that don't implement  the method and not for others, though.